# How to get next 10 days from current date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have dateformat string like this "2015-03-09".How do i get next 10 days date from current date?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: So you need next 10 days from that date ?

Comment: You did read Apple's "Date and Time Programming Guide" didn't you? What did you try and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 25):

For a purely Swift 3 solution:

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 10, to: Date())
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's how to get a date 10 days from now, using built-in date modification method .dateByAddingUnit
If all 10 days (dates) are required, can be looped by "value:10" part and added to array.

```
var tenDaysfromNow: NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 10, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])!
    }

    print(tenDaysfromNow)
```

And for Swift3:

```
var tenDaysfromNow: Date {
   return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 10, to: Date(), options: [])!
}
```

Comment: Calendar has no member 'dateByAddingUnit'

Comment: Of course. This was Swift2. Now for Swift 3:
var tenDaysfromNow: Date {
        return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 10, to: Date(), options: [])!
    }

Comment: What would be the correct way to get the next 10 days from a given date? Using Swift 3 response in a function. For example: `fun getTenDaysFromDate(date: Date) -> Date {...}`

Comment: In your Swift 3 example, you shouldn't be using `NSCalendar` at all. It's just `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: date)`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [dateByAddingTimeInterval()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval:) method for this.

```
var dateStr          = "2015-03-09"
var formatter        = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
var currDate         = formatter.dateFromString(dateStr)

for i in 1...10
{
    var interval = NSTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * i)
    var newDate = currDate?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)
    println(newDate)
}
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @Martin R in the comments, it'll be better to use [dateByAddingComponents()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:) of NSCalendar class:

```
var calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
var dateComponent = NSDateComponents()

for i in 1...10
{
    dateComponent.day = i
    var newDate = calendar?.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponent, toDate: currDate!, options:nil)
    println(newDate)

}
```

Comment: My comment to the other answer applies here as well.

Comment: @MartinR: He only needs the next 10 dates, right ? There is no time in the date string he has. So I think this won't cause any issue in that case. Correct me, If I'm wrong

Comment: The proper way to add a day is to use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

Comment: An NSDate is an absolute point in time. If you add 86400 seconds to "midnight" on a day with 25 hours (Daylight Saving Time transition) then you'll get a date on the same day at 23:00.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function 'dateByAddingTimeInterval()' for an NSDate object. With this, you can create a NSDate from your date string. Then add 10 days = 10*24*60*60 to get next 10 days NSDate value

```
let today : NSDate = ....
let next10days = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(10*60*60*24); //interval = seconds
//then you convert back to your date string format if you want, by using NSDateFormatter
```

To avoid problem with Daylighttime saving (@MartinR):

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
let next10Days = cal.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, value: 10, toDate: today, options: nil)
```

Comment: No, a day is not the same as 60*60*24 seconds. In regions with Daylight Saving Time a day can have 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: Yes, this solution will have a 'bug' when we change to Summer Time or Winter Time. We should use NSCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a swift 4/5 version of the answer by @MidhunMP

```
var dateStr          = "2015-03-09"
var formatter        = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
var dateComponent = DateComponents()

if let currDate = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
    for i in 1...10 {
        let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: currDate)
        print(newDate) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

For Swift 3:

```
let now = NSDate()
let plusTen = now.dateByAddingDays(10)
```

Comment: NSDate has no member 'dateByAddingDays'. You must be using an extension to do so.