# How to get next n days date from the given date

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to next 15 days date from current date, but when i tried to give custom date instead of current date, it not working.

```
 let date = sharedAppDelegate.dueDate
 let givenDate = Utility.convertStringToDate(format: "yyyy-MM-dd", 
dateString: date)

let futureDate = (givenDate as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: Date()) ?? Date()
```

Third line gives error like Date? is not convertible to NSCalendar.
Expected result:- futureDate should be next 15 date from givenDate

Comment: "givenDate as NSCalendar".. clearly says that you are converting date to calendar... which is 100% wrong and must give error.

Comment: Even this must be not working if you are using currentdate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next 10 days from current date in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875356/how-to-get-next-10-days-from-current-date-in-swift)

Comment: Replace line by this let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: value ?? Date()) ?? Date()

Comment: `Calendar.current` gives NSCalendar object, not Date object.... so it works... but if you case date into calendar then it will never work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **Date** is not a **Calendar**

You can use the `Calendar` to do calculations or comparisons on `Date` objects, in your case you want to use the Calendar to add `x` number of days to your starting date

Try

```
let startDate = Date()
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)

print(tomorrow)
```

OUTPUT:

> Optional(2019-06-01 07:14:48 +0000)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Date class like this.

```
extension Date {
   func dateByAddingDays(dateNum:Int) -> Date {
       return Calendar.gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: dateNum, to: self)!
   }
}
```

Now create date object

```
let today = Date()
let dayAfterTomorrow = today.dateByAddingDays(dateNum:2)
debugPrint(dayAfterTomorrow)
```